# Emacs: trouble using using markdown-preview-eww

Tags: emacs, markdown

I'm following the instructions on https://github.com/niku/markdown-preview-eww

I have installed markdown-preview-eww using MELPA, redcarpet using gem, restarted Emacs and opened a `.md` file. However I don't understand how am I supposed to "Execute `markdown-preview-eww`".

The search engines haven't helped me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely that means to run it via `execute-extended-command` (probably bound to `M-x`):

```
M-x markdown-preview-eww RET
```

Make sure to load the feature first, e.g via

```el
(require 'markdown-preview-eww)
```

Comment: That's what I thought but there no such command listed when pressing `M-x`. Should have mentioned that in the OP.

Comment: Hrm, that function [should be autoloaded](https://github.com/niku/markdown-preview-eww/blob/5853f836425c877c8a956501f0adda137ef1d3b7/markdown-preview-eww.el). Are you sure the library installed successfully from MELPA? Are you successfully using other packages from MELPA? Are you using `use-package` or similar?

Comment: The package is listed in installed packages (verified via `M-x package-delete`). I have installed and used several other packages using MELPA. Don't use `use-package` etc. [edit. I'm running on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS desktop, have the same issue on Debian WSL.]

Comment: @Keyboard_Crasher, in that case I suspect you aren't loading the library. I normally install and load via `use-package`, but something like the `require` snippet I added to my answer should do it for you.